# Hereditary algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

I have the following problem: If $\Lambda$ is a hereditary, basic and connected algebra and $e$ is an idempotent of $\Lambda$, how can I prove that $e\Lambda e$ is also hereditary?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: And are you assuming finite dimensional?  Over any field or an algebraically closed field?  This does smell like homework.

Comment: If you are assuming finite dimensional and split basic, here is a hint. Assume $\Lambda$ is the path algebra of an acyclic quiver. Convince yourself that you may assume that $e$ is a sum of primitive idempotents corresponding to vertices.  Show that $e\Lambda e$ is a path algebra on a certain subquiver. 

Comment: Is not a homework is just that Im interested in studying this things and I found that problem. Yes I assume $\Lambda$ is finite dimensional and is over any field.

Comment: By basic, do you mean split basic (the radical quotient is a product of copies of the field) or just that the radical quotient is a direct product of division rings?

Comment: The definition of basic that Im considered is the next one:

If $\Lambda$ is a $k$-algebra with a complete set ${e_{1},...,e_{n}}$ of primitive orthogonal idempotents, then $\Lambda$ is basic if $e_{i}\Lambda$ is not isomorphic to $e_{j}\Lambda$ for all $i\noteq j$

Comment: So i think it is equivalent to what you call split basic

Comment: Split means in addition $f\Lambda f$ is the field for all primitive idempotents f. 

Comment: Ok, to be honest i have no idea of how to solve this problem... so if you could give a simple proof of it... im really new in this area

Comment: @Antonio - I suggest editing the question so that it contains all the assumptions and relevant definitions. Not everyone will read down the discussion in comments to find out what you really meant.

Comment: This question was asked a few hours later at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87541/hereditary-algebras and answered there. Antonio, if you happen to be also Joe at math.se, please do not ask the same question at both sites, and if you *must*, then including links between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\Lambda$ is split basic, then by Gabriel's theorem it is isomorphic to $\Bbbk Q$ where $Q$ is a finite acyclic quiver.  Up to isomorphism you can assume $e$ is the sum of empty paths running over some subset $X$ of vertices. Then $e\Lambda e$ is isomorphic to the path algebra on the full (i.e. induced) subquiver on the vertex set $X$. Thus it is hereditary.